# What does NHibernate.Search ContainedIn attribute do?

Tags: nhibernate, lucene, lucene.net, nhibernate.search

And how it differs from IndexedEmbedded?

P.s. and what's the best source of information about NHibernate.Search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Answer

The ContainedInAttribute is used in conjunction with the IndexedEmbeddedAttribute. The ContainedInAttribute is used as a sort of marker, that points back to a class that uses and IndexedEmbeddedAttribute. This tells NHibernate.Search that when you update that class, you want to update the parent's full text index. This is good when you update a child of a owning class and you want the owner's index also updated.

below is an example of how to use this.

```
[Indexed]
class Parent
{
     [IndexedEmbeded]
     public Child SomeChild { get; set; }
}

class Child
{
     [ContainedIn]
     public Parent MyParent { get; set; }
}
```

Note: The ContainedIn attribute is useless if you are pointing to an owning parent that is not using an IndexEmbeded attribute.

2. Answer

Documentation Information is from hibernate search, but most things here apply to NHibernate.Search as well.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en/html/

or

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en/html_single/